# Bash scripts only run when using bash command

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, debian

Today, my working bash scripts stopped working on my Debian 11 server.

```
$ ./CCrec.sh
-bash: ./CCrec.sh: Permission denied
```

Fails even if using sudo.

Yes, the permissions are set correctly. (They've been working for years.)

```
$ ls -l CCrec.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 user1 user1 858 Jan 23 20:30 CCrec.sh
```

Another clue: autotab it doesn't recognize the script is present with beginning with "./". This makes me think the's a change in my bashrc, but I'm not noticing a change.

script will run when specifying bash:

```
$ bash CCrec.sh 
This is working
```

Any solutions?

Comment: To rule out the usual suspects and get some more hints, could you hit it with a `chmod +x CCrec.sh` and try running a different script in the same directory?

Comment: Are you logged in as user1?

Comment: Some weird issues happend to me once because I forgot to add a shebang (`#! /bin/bash`) at the top of my script. Hope that'll help

Comment: You didn't show the content of CCrec.sh

Comment: @Vincent : If a typical shell is running a script with missing a #! line, it would usually revert to `sh` for running it. AFIK, bash is a bit different, in that it then runs the script as `bash` script. In any case, I don't think the reason for the error is the **missing** #!. Perhaps it is a **mistyped** #! - one which refers to a file which exists, but is lacking permissions.